# How to customize pallet_contracts?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, pallet-contracts

We have our own chain where we've added `pallet_contracts` pallet for writing and deploying smart contract. We just want to give permission to upload smart contract for few users only. Someone please gives some advice how can we implement this features?

Answer (score 2):

That's is a very interesting feature, I would like to see cool approaches and ideas in the responses of this question.

I don't think you can get this functionality with the current `pallet_contracts` (But I might be wrong). Anyone (or any program) that has tokens of the chain can upload a smart contract without requiring permission using this pallet.

I can think of two options here:

1. The first one and the less recommended is to copy the code of the pallet into a new pallet `custom_pallet_contracts` and modify the code to let only authorised users upload the contract. For that you only need to create a new storage where you keep a list of all the users with permissions to upload contracts, and modify the [upload_contract](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L609C10-L609C21) extrinsic in order to check that the origin is in that list.
2. The second option is a bit more complex but definitely is the one I recommend to go. Create a new pallet that acts a "wrapper pallet" for the `pallet_contract` where you can add additional logic like check if the origin can upload the contract.

   The idea is not mine, is from Sergei and Shawn, and they created a tutorial about it 4 years ago: [Extending Substrate Runtime Modules](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/extending-substrate-runtime-modules/).
   You can see the code of this "wrapper pallet" here: [Sudo Contract](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/sudo-contract) .

   The tutorial is amazing but is outdated so you won't probably be able to use the same code, but you will get the concept and understand the logic and the steps needed:

   - In your new pallet expose the same extrinsic calls as the `pallet_contracts` (in your case at least the `upload_contract`) and forwards those calls to the real `pallet_contracts`.
   - Before forwards those calls to the real `pallet_contracts`, add your  authorization checks logic.
   - In your node make the `pallet_contracts` pallet "Un-Callable" so the `upload_contract` extrinsic has to be called within your "wrapper pallet"

Another example of this concept of extending functionality of a current pallet is the [NFTs Royalty Pallet](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/nfts-royalty-pallet/3766), which is a "wrapped pallet" that manages a royalties for the `nft_pallet`, locking the transfer in the `nft_pallet` and forcing users to make the NFT transfers within the `nft_royalties_pallet` that has some extra logic on top of it.